# How can I deploy my extension to magento

Tags: javascript, magento, shopify

For example I have a extension which calls a java script which does some search and returns a list. Now;

How can I deploye this extension to magento or shopify store?Is there any source where I can get complete process details?

Comment: You need to build an app for that on Shopify.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any good source from where I can get an Idea of creating app in a short time?

Comment: It depends on the type of the app.. Private or Public?

Comment: It will be a public app